# my 2nd if statement is being ignored dont know why

Tags: java

Hello guys i am  basically creating a program that takes about 5 inputs from users and stores them in an array called course....every time user enter 1 course i want to ask the user if he wants to continue.. if he type yes the program continues or else it shows the values in array(course)......

**i am facing issues :-**

1.i dont wanna ask user to continue if he is already entering the last value which is 5th one.

2.my 2nd loop is basically being ignored i dont know why if it works every thing would've been ok.

3.if the user enters last value and press yes according to my program it is still not printing the values in my course(array).

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ArrayExample;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author jodh_
 */
public class ArrayExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] course = new String[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Please enter course name " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            Scanner gettingname = new Scanner(System.in);
            String coursenames = gettingname.nextLine();
            course[i] = coursenames;

            if (i < 4) {
               for(int j =0; j<4; j++){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)");
                Scanner gettingYesOrNo = new Scanner(System.in);
                String input = gettingYesOrNo.nextLine();

                if (input.equals("yes") || input.equals("y") || input.equals("Y") || input.equals("YES") || input.equals("Yes")) {
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;

                } else if (input.isEmpty()) {

                    System.out.println("Input cannot be empty!! Please try again");

                } else if (input.equals("no") || input.equals("No") || input.equals("NO") || input.equals("n") || input.equals("N")) {

                    System.out.println("Your select courses are as follows");
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < i + 1; x++) {
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a fence post problem to me. Also if(input.toLowerCase().startsWith("y") is much much simpler than all of those ors. Finally System.exit(0); IS THE CULPRIT.

Comment: Don't forget to *close* your Scanners.

Comment: when i reach the last stage of program which is please enter 5th course: and when i enter the course it should close the program and print the array values using this loop                                                                     
                for (int x = 0; x < i + 1; x++) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);
            }                                                                          but its not working instead it asks me wanna continue? and even if i say yes it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why code formatting is so very important! Spacing the nested if/else if/for statements allows you to follow the logic of your program much quicker and easier.

Here is a formatted version of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/** * * @author jodh_ */

public class ArrayExample
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String[] course = new String[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter course name " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        Scanner gettingname = new Scanner(System.in);
        String coursenames = gettingname.nextLine();

        course[i] = coursenames;

        if (i < 4)
        {
            for(int j =0; j<4; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)");
                Scanner gettingYesOrNo = new Scanner(System.in);
                String input = gettingYesOrNo.nextLine();

                if (input.equals("yes") || input.equals("y") || input.equals("Y") || input.equals("YES") || input.equals("Yes"))
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
                }
                else if (input.isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println("Input cannot be empty!! Please try again");
                }
                else if (input.equals("no") || input.equals("No") || input.equals("NO") || input.equals("n") || input.equals("N"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Your select courses are as follows");
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < i + 1; x++)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In this formatted code we can easily see where each piece of code is being executed.

If you take a look at the part that checks for "yes" you will see that if the conditions are met it breaks out of the inner for loop. This means that all code underneath this break within the inner loop is not executed if the user gives an answer of "yes".

```
                if (input.equals("yes") || input.equals("y") || input.equals("Y") || input.equals("YES") || input.equals("Yes"))
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
                }
```

Your print statement is inside this inner for loop, which in fact means that it will only execute if the conditions of the "yes" if statement are not met. If you were to input the text "cat" in the "would you like to continue?" prompt it would skip all the if/else if statements since none of them are being met, execute the print loop, output the courses, and System.exit(0); terminate the program.

It appears that the intended purpose is to output the courses if the user inputs "no". So lets see if we can move the print loop inside the "no" if.

```
            else if (input.equals("no") || input.equals("No") || input.equals("NO") || input.equals("n") || input.equals("N"))
            {
                System.out.println("Your select courses are as follows");
                for (int x = 0; x < i + 1; x++)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

This will output the courses only if the user inputs "no". And then it will termanate the program. Perfect!

So lets talk about this empty input condition:

```
            else if (input.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Input cannot be empty!! Please try again");
            }
```

Unless you need to specifically check that the input is empty you probably want to replace this with just an else statement. Lets see what that would look like.

```
            if (input.equals("yes") || input.equals("y") || input.equals("Y") || input.equals("YES") || input.equals("Yes"))
            {
                System.out.println("");
                break;

            }
            else if (input.equals("no") || input.equals("No") || input.equals("NO") || input.equals("n") || input.equals("N"))
            {
                System.out.println("Your select courses are as follows");
                for (int x = 0; x < i + 1; x++)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input!! Please try again.");
                j--;
            }
```

You need to decrement j because at the end of the for loop it will increment forward to the next course. Since the user input was invalid we want to keep the course iterator right where it is and continue to ask the user if they woud like to continue until a valid selection has been made.

We're almost there!

Now that we have sorted the input conditions, what happens when the user reaches the 5th course?

Right now we only have the courses print if the user answers "no". So at the end of the course loop we need to print the full course string array. The final product looks like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/** * * @author jodh_ */

public class ArrayExample
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String[] course = new String[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Please enter course name " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        Scanner gettingname = new Scanner(System.in);
        String coursenames = gettingname.nextLine();
        course[i] = coursenames;

        if (i < 4)
        {
            for(int j =0; j<4; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)");
                Scanner gettingYesOrNo = new Scanner(System.in);
                String input = gettingYesOrNo.nextLine();

                if (input.equals("yes") || input.equals("y") || input.equals("Y") || input.equals("YES") || input.equals("Yes"))
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;

                }
                else if (input.equals("no") || input.equals("No") || input.equals("NO") || input.equals("n") || input.equals("N"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Your select courses are as follows");
                    for (int x = 0; x < i + 1; x++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);
                    }
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input!! Please try again");
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your select courses are as follows");
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);
    }
}
}
```

Note: There are more optimal ways to get to the same result but I tried to keep the code as close to the original logic as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine if you change the `break` to `continue`.Try my code.

```
    String[] course = new String[5];      
    for (int  i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter course name " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        Scanner gettingname = new Scanner(System.in);
        String coursenames = gettingname.nextLine();
        course[i] = coursenames;
        if (i < 4){
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)");
            Scanner gettingYesOrNo = new Scanner(System.in);
            input = gettingYesOrNo.nextLine();

            if (input.equals("yes") || input.equals("y") || input.equals("Y") || input.equals("YES") || input.equals("Yes")) {
                System.out.println("");
                continue;

            } else if (input.isEmpty()) {

                System.out.println("Input cannot be empty!! Please try again");

            } else if (input.equals("no") || input.equals("No") || input.equals("NO") || input.equals("n") || input.equals("N")) {

                System.out.println("Your select courses are as follows");
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < i + 1; x++) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
Please enter course name 1: 
androiid

Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)
y

Please enter course name 2: 
dsfnfv

Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)
y

Please enter course name 3: 
sfgngff

Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)
y

Please enter course name 4: 
grgngr

Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)
y

Please enter course name 5: 
fgmt

1: androiid

2: dsfnfv

3: sfgngff

4: grgngr

5: fgmt

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: But wouldn't that make it print the course array every iteration?

Comment: Nope, last `For` loop is out of all.And it is working fine on my system. I am posting the output too.

Comment: thank you guys for taking your time and helping thank you so much both of you guys are great thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1):

I've made quite a few changes in your code like removing some unnecessary loops but its working now

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String[] course = new String[5];

Scanner gettingname = new Scanner(System.in);

int i=0;    
for (; i < 5; i++) {

        System.out.println("Please enter course name " + (i + 1) + ": ");

        course[i] =gettingname.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            if(i==4) break;
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)");
            Scanner gettingYesOrNo = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = gettingYesOrNo.nextLine();

            if (input.equals("yes") || input.equals("y") || input.equals("Y") || input.equals("YES") || input.equals("Yes")) {
                System.out.println("");
                continue;

            } 
            else if (input.isEmpty()) {

                System.out.println("Input cannot be empty!! Please try again");

            } 
            else if (input.equals("no") || input.equals("No") || input.equals("NO") || input.equals("n") || input.equals("N")) {

               break;

            }

            }

             System.out.println("Your select courses are as follows");
            for (int x = 0; x < i+1 ; x++) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println((x + 1) + ": " + course[x]);


        }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I wrote that might fix your program. You'll have to implement the rest but it should be easy enough.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] course = new String[5];
        String yesOrNo;
        int index = 0;
        do{
            System.out.println("Please enter course name " + (index + 1) + ": ");
            course[index] = input.nextLine();   
            if(index < 4) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue? ((y)Yes / (n)No)");
                yesOrNo = input.nextLine();
            }
            index++;
        }while(yesOrNo.toLowerCase().startsWith("y) && index < 5) 

        //if the loop is exited then we know either the user chose not to continue or all the course names have been filled
        //handle that here
    }
}
```

The logic of what I did:

1. The while loop condition makes it so that you won't continue looping when all the courses are filled. And inside of the loop it checks if the index is not 4.
2. there's no more need for your second loop
3. you can print your array after the loop now.
4. Making two scanners is completely useless and takes up memory because you didn't even close them.

I hope this helps.